# ¿Se pueden hacer ArrayList de ArrayList? - Java

Tags: java

Seria de gran utilidad, si se puede me explicaran como hacerlo. He intentado de varias maneras pero no lo logro.

Comment: Debe mostrar lo que ha intentado, asi sera mas facil ayudar

Comment: tan solo con buscar en google, ya te explican... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147799/java-arraylist-of-arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare un codigo a modo de ejemplo mira:

```
//creamos una List que contendra una List de String
List<List<String>> listaDeLista = new ArrayList<>();

//creamos la primera List de String y le añadimos elementos
List<String> listaStringUno = new ArrayList<>();
listaStringUno.add("Cadena uno");
listaStringUno.add("Cadena dos");
//añadimos la List de String a la List de List
listaDeLista.add(listaStringUno);

//creamos la segunda List de String y le añadimos elementos
List<String> listaStringDos = new ArrayList<>();
listaStringDos.add("Cadena tres");
//añadimos la List de String a la List de List
listaDeLista.add(listaStringDos);

//creamos la tercera List de String y le añadimos elementos
List<String> listaStringTres = new ArrayList<>();
listaStringTres.add("Cadena cuatro");
listaStringTres.add("Cadena cinco");
//añadimos la List de String a la List de List
listaDeLista.add(listaStringTres);

//imprimimos la lista de listas
System.out.println(listaDeLista);
```

Espero te sirva 
Saludos